# ComponentDidUpdate SetState ReactJS Infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Even though there are many questions with the same subject line, I could not get an answer for my problem.

**Problem**

I have a select dropdown. On click of which, I call an Api which fetches some key values. I consider this set of key value input fields as a component. So each and every time onChange of my select drop-down, I have used lifecycle methods to handle API Calls. Also, I record these input key values and send back their state to parent component.

According to ReactJS lifecycle methods:

I use

**componentDidMount**
To call the API for the first time after initial render. This works.

**componentDidUpdate**
To call the API for subsequent API calls on select drop-down change. But here is the problem. When I try to update the state of input fields the program falls into an infinite loop and hence there are infinite API calls. I am pretty sure after debugging that the problem is with setState(), But I couldnt find the best way to handle states in componentDidUpdate method.

This [link](https://github.com/joshwnj/words/blob/master/react-infinite-loop.md) exactly replicates my problem but i want a standardized solution

Hope this is clear.
Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you cannot setState() inside componentDidUpdate it would lead to infinite loop.Instead you can call a function onChange event and change the state there.

Comment: thanks! I understood the workaround. But ReactJS documents suggest that we can set states in componentDidUpdate. Was wondering how i have misunderstood the concept. http://busypeoples.github.io/post/react-component-lifecycle/   Please check this blog and can you tell me where i have went wrong?

Comment: when you setState() inside componentDidUpdate then it would call  following lifecycle : shouldComponetUpdate-->componentWillUpdate--->render---and again ---->componentDidUpdate . In this way it creates infinite loop.

Comment: This is false. You *can* call `setState` in `componentDidUpdate`, please see my answer.

Answer (score 7):

This is spelled out pretty clearly in [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate):

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  // Typical usage (don't forget to compare props):
  if (this.props.userID !== prevProps.userID) {
    this.fetchData(this.props.userID);
  }
}
```

> You **may call setState() immediately** in componentDidUpdate() but note
>   that **it must be wrapped in a condition** like in the example above, or
>   you’ll cause an infinite loop.

Comment: Hello @Madbreaks I have a timer i just define a counter in state and when componentDidMount i do setInterval to decrease the timer and in component Did update i want to change a color to text in my screen but i got the same error `componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.state.timer === 0) {
      clearInterval(this.interval);
      this.setState({
        resendColor: '#257bd1',
        // disable: false,
      });
    }
  }`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setState()` within `componentDidUpdate()`. But you have to use the condition for that. Otherwise, it get infinite loop.

As the example,

```
 componentDidUpdate(){
    if(this.props.id !== this.state.id) {
        this.setState({
            id: this.props.id 
        });
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because setState triggers a call to componentDidUpdate.

When componentDidUpdate is called, setState does not check whether or not state change has occurred. It simply calls componentDidUpdate again and again, which leads to stackoverflow.

```
  class Component extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {changeState: false}
    }
    componentDidMount(){
      this.setState({changeState: true});
    }
    componentDidUpdate(){
        this.setState({changeState: false});
    } 
 }
```

Here, first changeState is set to false in constructor, and then componentDidMount is triggered, which sets state of changeState to true. This state change triggers componentDidUpdate, which sets the state of changeState again to true. This triggers componentDidUpdate again and again.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the real difference between two state objects.
Below you can find my solution, My state object has movies, which is an array of objects. I edited and movie and then comparing these two arrays.

```
    async componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {

        if (prevState.movies.filter (e => this.state.movies.includes(e))) {
        const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:3002/movies");
        this.setState({ movies: response.data })
    }
}
```