# When state is updated, component does not re-render with updated state (REACT)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

Ok so let me just start with this code probably looks like a mess but the problem is pretty simple I think.

So whenever I change the state in the parent of the below 'TitleCards' child component, the state changes in the child component too but the portfolioTotal value in the render method of the 'TitleCards' component does not recalculate based on the changed state. I think it has something to do with the async function, but I'm not sure.

Any ideas? All I want is when the state changes in the child component (which I can see with dev tools that it is changing), for the component to automatically re-render/recalculate portfolioTotal with the changed state.

```
import "./StockCard.css";
import { IEX } from "./IEX.js";
import moment from 'moment';
import Folder from "./folder.png";
import MoneyBag from "./money-bag.png";
import Handshake from "./hand-shake.png";
import add from "./add.png";
import NumberFormat from 'react-number-format';

const LOGO_API = "https://eodhistoricaldata.com/img/logos/US/";

class TitleCards extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.arr = this.totalPortfolio();
        this.state ={
            portfolioTotal: '',
            WhenThisChangesShouldntTheComponentReRender: this.props.info,
        }
        this.totalPortfolio = this.totalPortfolio.bind(this);
        this.getIntradayPrice = this.getIntradayPrice.bind(this);

    }

    static defaultProps = {
        TitleCardInfo: [
          { name: "Portfolio", ticker: "DIA"}, 
          { name: "Total Return", ticker: "SPY"}, 
          { name: "Positions Held", ticker: "IWM"}, 
          { name: "Add Position", ticker: "Gold"},],
      }

    async getIntradayPrice(tick) {
        const resp = await fetch(`${IEX.base_url}/stock/${tick}/intraday-prices?chartLast=1&token=${IEX.api_token}`);
        return resp.json();
      }

    async totalPortfolio() {
        const { info } = this.props;
        const respPromises = info.map(({ tick }) => this.getIntradayPrice(tick));
        const respArrays = await Promise.all(respPromises);
        const result = respArrays.reduce((acc, val, index) => acc + val[0].close * info[index].amtPurch, 0);
        return result;
      }
      
    componentDidMount() {
        this.totalPortfolio()
          .then(portfolioTotal => {
            this.setState({
              portfolioTotal
            });
          })
        .catch(error => {
            // add any required error handling/messaging here
        });
    }

    render(){  
        const { portfolioTotal } = this.state;
        return(
            <div className="positioning">
                <div className="StockCardTitle">
                    <img src={Folder} className="StockCardTitle-image" />  
                    {portfolioTotal}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default TitleCards;
```

Parent Component where state changes and is passed down to TitleCard Component, if its of any help.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import StockCard from "./StockCard";
import TitleCards from "./TitleCards";
import { IEX } from "./IEX.js";

const LOGO_API = "https://eodhistoricaldata.com/img/logos/US/";

class UserInput extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state ={
            tickerName: "",
            sAmtPurch: "",
            sPurchPrice: "",
            sDatePurch: "",
            tickerList: [
                { tick: "AAPL", amtPurch: 50, purchPrice: 10, datePurch: "01/01/2021"},
                { tick: "GOOG", amtPurch: "40", purchPrice: "10", datePurch: "01/01/2021"},
                { tick: "TSLA", amtPurch: "40", purchPrice: "10", datePurch: "01/01/2021"},
                { tick: "J", amtPurch: "40", purchPrice: "10", datePurch: "01/01/2021"},
                { tick: "AMZN", amtPurch: "40", purchPrice: "10", datePurch: "01/01/2021"},
                { tick: "FB", amtPurch: "40", purchPrice: "10", datePurch: "01/01/2021"},
                { tick: "BABA", amtPurch: "40", purchPrice: "10", datePurch: "01/01/2021"},
                { tick: "JNJ", amtPurch: "40", purchPrice: "10", datePurch: "01/01/2021"},
                { tick: "JPM", amtPurch: "40", purchPrice: "10", datePurch: "01/01/2021"},
                { tick: "XOM", amtPurch: "30", purchPrice: "10", datePurch: "01/01/2021"},
                ],
            data4: {}
        }
        this.handler = this.handler.bind(this)
    }

    handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        // Initialize state into variables 
        const tickerToBeAdded = { tick: this.state.tickerName, amtPurch: this.state.sAmtPurch, purchPrice: this.state.sPurchPrice, datePurch: this.state.sDatePurch};
        const tickerList = this.state.tickerList;
        
        // Apend tickerList with inputed ticker
        const length = tickerList.length;
        tickerList[length] = tickerToBeAdded;
        this.setState({
            tickerList: tickerList
        })
    }
    handleInputChange = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        // Store Input in State
        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        })
    }

    componentDidMount() {
    // query the api
    const url4 = `${IEX.base_url}/stock/${this.state.tickerList.tick}/intraday-prices?chartLast=1&token=${IEX.api_token}`;
    fetch(url4)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data4) => {
        this.setState({
          data4: data4[data4.length - 1],
        });
      });
    }

    render () {

        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <p><input type='text' placeholder='Stock Ticker' name='tickerName' onChange={this.handleInputChange}/></p>
                    <p><input type='text' placeholder='Shares' name='sAmtPurch' onChange={this.handleInputChange}/></p>
                    <p><input type='text' placeholder='Purchase Price' name='sPurchPrice' onChange={this.handleInputChange}/></p>
                    <p><button>Send Message</button></p>
                </form>

                <div className="Charts">
                        <TitleCards info={this.state.tickerList}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default UserInput;
```

Comment: you can use event listener  in that case. Because state change in Child component wont directly trigger re-render cycle.

Comment: All I understood is `TitleCards` is your child component and change in value of state `portfolioTotal ` is triggering re render in `TitleCards` but not triggering in `UserInput ` . If I am understanding correctly or its the other way ?

Comment: When info from the prop changes the component will re-render but there is nothing that will change portfolioTotal. It is kept in state of the child component and only place you set it is in componentDidMount which gets executed once at mount. If you want to recalculate portfolioTotal you should change componentDidMount to componentDidUpdate so that it gets executed whenever props change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`componentDidMount` only fires once per mount. If you want to run something every time the component re-renders, you need `componentDidUpdate`. Take a look at this [lifecycle diagram](https://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/) for what method to use.

Be careful when using `componentDidUpdate` with `this.setState`. If you blindly update state every cycle in componentDidUpdate, you'll trigger an infinite loop. (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54318043/4060061) for details.)

Comment: Do you have an idea of what the conditional that wraps the componentDidUpdate should include? I tried the below but got the infinite loop. What the second value in the if statement is is what Im lost on. `    componentDidUpdate() {
        if (this.state.portfolioTotal == ???? ) {
        this.totalPortfolio()
          .then(portfolioTotal => {
            this.setState({
              portfolioTotal
            });
          })
        .catch(error => {
            // add any required error handling/messaging here
        });
    }
    }`

Comment: Without seeing your full code and knowing your intent, I can't tell you for certain. Think about the if like this: It should only be true when you want to get a new portfolio. Maybe that means something like `if (Boolean(this.state.portfolioTotal))` which would evaluate to false only if there's never been a portfolioTotal. Maybe that means something like `if (moreThan30SecondsAgo(lastFetchTime))`.